Error when using Amazon Q Developer with IDE: "The project you have selected for source code is too large"
I am getting an error when using Amazon Q Developer, when using "/dev" functionality in Androiod Studio.
"Sorry, we encountered a problem when processing your request.
The project you have selected for source code is too large to use as context. Please select a different folder to use for this conversation".
I am not able to see in the documentation what is the limit of the source code, and if there is any possible workaround to limit to only a single file, as when trying to select a folder, it comes with error:
"The selected folder is not in an opened workspace folder. Add the selected folder to the workspace or pick a new folder". Anyone knows a workaround or how to solve this issue?
I have tried changing the folder, but does not work either. I am expecting to generate the code suggestions.
